# Problem while building wsp of a solution containing mutiple projects

Tags: 2010, solution-package, gac

I have a SharePoint solution having many projects in it, dlls generated by each project is placed in GAC, now whenever I build the solution and generate the wsp, i can see an old version of a particular project dll is included in the wsp, though inside bin/Debug folder of that particular project the updated dll is present, after deployment if i remove that particular dll from assembly and re-install the new version(bin/Debug version), then only my solution is working properly, can any one explain this behavior?

Things I already checked

1. Checked manifest.xml if everything is configured properly
2. Checked project dependencies and build order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your projects probably includes a reference to the DLL from a different location than the rest.  Go through each of the projects in the solution, expand the References, then click on the reference to the library in question.  Look at the Path property and make note of where it is getting the library from.  My bet is that one of them is pointing to someplace other than the expected location.

Comment: Hi I already checked project dependencies and reference also, each project refers to some other project of same solution, no external referencing

Comment: Another option is to do a search of your drives and delete all local copies of that library, including from the GAC, and then rebuild your solution.  If there is a bad reference, then the build should fail as it can no longer find the old DLL.  That should at least point you towards the problem project